# What algorithm is used for computing a circle with floating point radius?

Tags: c#, c++, geometry

The [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) is well suited for computing circles when their radius is an integer.

```
void CircleOptimized(int xc, int yc, int r, int color) {
    unsigned int x= r, y= 0;//local coords     
    int          cd2= 0;    //current distance squared - radius squared
    if (!r) return; 
    drawpixel(xc-r, yc, color);
    drawpixel(xc+r, yc, color);
    drawpixel(xc, yc-r, color);
    drawpixel(xc, yc+r, color);
    while (x > y) {    //only formulate 1/8 of circle
        cd2-= (--x) - (++y);
        if (cd2 < 0) cd2+=x++;
        drawpixel(xc-x, yc-y, color);//upper left left
        drawpixel(xc-y, yc-x, color);//upper upper left
        drawpixel(xc+y, yc-x, color);//upper upper right
        drawpixel(xc+x, yc-y, color);//upper right right
        drawpixel(xc-x, yc+y, color);//lower left left
        drawpixel(xc-y, yc+x, color);//lower lower left
        drawpixel(xc+y, yc+x, color);//lower lower right
        drawpixel(xc+x, yc+y, color);//lower right right
     } 
}
```

For example, when passed `r=1` and `r=2` the outputs are as follows respectively:

```
.....  .XXX.
..X..  X...X
.X.X.  X...X
..X..  X...X
.....  .XXX.
 r=1    r=2
```

However, I need a couple more steps between `r=1` and `r=2`. Perhaps (hypothetically) `r=1.33` and `r=1.66` which might look like this:

```
.....  .....  ..X..  .XXX.
..X..  .XXX.  .X.X.  X...X
.X.X.  .X.X.  X...X  X...X
..X..  .XXX.  .X.X.  X...X
.....  .....  ..X..  .XXX.
r=1.0  r=1.3  r=1.6  r=2.0
```

However, when I try to adapt the algorithm above to use floating point arithmetic (with or without rounding), it loses its symmetry and generates discontinuous paths (resulting in some very odd shapes).

Is there a more suited algorithm for my purposes?

Comment: So, you are asking why a version of code you are *not* showing does not work? See any problem here? ;-)

Comment: Anyway, this whole algorithm is based in integer arithmetic. Either use integers with scaling, or use the basic *sin* and *cos* formula for circle.

Comment: @hyde It seemed awfully trivial to copy and paste the block of code replacing just `int` with `float`, and then another copy and paste with an added `round`.

Comment: @hyde Or you can use the circle equation, `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`. It allows you to do hinting (based on the difference between the left and right side of the equation) very easily, and if the radius is relatively low (you seem to be working with very small circles), it should be quite fast (note that you only need to do this for one quarter of the circle - the other three are simple mirrors). In any case, why do you care about optimizing circle drawing? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: One approach is to hard code the few special cases, say 1.3, 1.6, 2.5. Then use the integer algorithm for the rest. That is, if you don't want/need antialising, and don't need more special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in simple fractions (like 4/3 and 5/3), I'd oversample (i.e. use subpixels, here 9 sub-pixels per pixels, so compute circles with radius 4 and 5 subpixels) and then deduce a good value of the pixel from the sub-pixels.  If you deduce to something else than ON, OFF you are doing anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Basic circle drawing ...

```
public void DrawCircle(float stepSize, float radius, int colour)
{
    float x, y;
    float angle;

    while (angle < 2*Math.PI)
    {
        x = radius * cos(angle);
        y = radius * sin(angle);
        // decide how to round your floating point X,Y here ...
        drawpixel(x,y,colour);
        angle += stepSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finding `step` and `decide how to round` are 2 biggest problems. Solving them would be more problematic, than adapting midpoint circle algorithm methink.

Comment: Well, `step` is just how smooth you want your circle to be - you could come up with a scaling for step based on your radius if you're worried about too many steps for your circle size. And so long as your `decide how to round` is consistent (e.g. always round down) then you won't end up with the disconnected segments you'll get with the midpoint circle algorithm.

Comment: if you take too small step, or your decision doesn't take in account decision made for closest pixels - you end up drawing 2 circles at once: with removed fractions and with rounding up (to example, for 1.3 it will be 1 and 2). Finding proper step and decision of rounding is the challenge. Try drawing that small circle yourself. I am not saying your answer is wrong, it's correct, but it's too general and maybe not suited well for a given question ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think that Taylor approximation may be useful

- calculate the x in x^2= r^2- y^2 using the first order Taylor approximation (sqrt(u^2 + a) = u + a / 2u)